# Como decodificar muitas colunas de um data frame do R

Tags: r

Possuo um data frame com mais de 300 colunas que são categóricas mas estão codificadas como numéricas. Cada uma destas colunas possui um "tipo" próprio, ou seja, possui uma tabela de codificação própria.
O meu problema é criar um novo data frame com as variáveis decodificadas.

Tenho carregado os seguintes data frames:

- o data frame principal chamado "dados", que possui 347 colunas que eu quero decodificar.
- um data frame auxiliar chamado "dados_vars" com: nome (variable.name) e "tipo" (data.type) de todas as variáveis do df principal
- um data frame auxiliar chamado "codes": com "tipo" (data.type), códigos possíveis (value) para o "tipo" respectivo e o significado (content) de cada código

Estou tentando usar o dplyr para tentar facilitar.
O que eu consegui fazer até agora foi:

```
# pego uma das variáveis do df principal 
variavel <- "abc"
# busco no df "dados_vars" qual é o tipo desta variável
tipo.variavel <- as.character(dados_vars[dados_vars$variable.name == variavel, "data.type"])
# filtro no df "codes" os códigos específicos que esta variável pode ter
codigos <- codes %>% filter(data.type==tipo.variável) %>% select(value,content)
# crio um novo data frame com esta variável decodificada
novos.dados <- mutate(dados, var1=factor(var1,label=codigos$content,levels=codigos$value))
```

Agora, como eu faço para aplicar este procedimento a todas as colunas do df principal?

Comment: Se for só pra transformar seu código em algo que funcione pra todas variáveis, você pode colocar dentro de um `for (i in 1:347)` e definir `var1 <- paste0("var", i)`. Você pode trocar o `for` por um `lapply` e verificar se a performance melhora, também.

Comment: Para facilitar a explicação do problema descrevi as variáveis com o nome de "varX" mas, na verdade, cada variável tem um nome diferente.

Comment: Nesse caso, outra possibilidade é você trocar var por `colnames(dados)[i]`. Se entendi bem, isso resolveria.

Comment: Sim, isto vai na direção da solução dada pelo @Rcoster e que, em princípio, resolve o meu problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei adotando a solução abaixo, seguindo as dicas dadas.

```
for (i in colnames(dados)){
    tipo.variavel <- as.character(dados_vars[dados_vars$variable.name == i, "data.type"])
    fatores.variavel <- subset(codes,toupper(data.type)==toupper(tipo.variavel), c("value","content"))
    dados[,paste0(i,".new")] <- factor(dados[,i],labels=fatores.variavel$content,levels=fatores.variavel$value)
}
```

Agradeço pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução usando o pacote base:

```
dados <- data.frame(replicate(10, sample(1:3, 10, rep = T)))
dados_vars <- data.frame(variable.name = paste0('X', 1:10), data.type = sample(1:4, 10, rep = T))
codes <- data.frame(tipo = rep(1:4, each = 3), value = rep(1:3, 4), code = letters[1:12])

for (i in colnames(dados)) {
    tipo.atual <- dados_vars[dados_vars$variable.name == i, 'data.type']
    dados[, i] <- factor(dados[, i], levels = subset(codes, tipo == tipo.atual)$value, labels = subset(codes, tipo == tipo.atual)$code)
}
```

Comment: Infelizmente esta solução não funcionou nos meus data frames. Por exemplo, se eu faço: `i <- "hxadd"      tipo.atual <- dados_vars[dados_vars$variable.name == i, 'data.type']      dados[, i] <- factor(dados[, i], levels = subset(codes, data.type == tipo.atual)$value, labels = subset(codes, data.type == tipo.atual)$code)`, dá a seguinte mensagem de erro: `Error in Ops.factor(data.type, tipo.atual) : level sets of factors are different`

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema do erro "level sets factors are differents" usando o meu código inicial só que ao invés de fazer a referência pelo nome da variável, faço agora a referência pelo índice i. Assim, a solução do @Rcoster funciona, tendo a vantagem de eu manipular algumas colunas de forma diferente (por exemplo, algumas colunas, ao invés de se buscar um código, devem ser discretizadas e eu  uso o `cut` para isso). No entanto, como eu faço para manter as colunas originais no df (ficando este com as colunas codificadas e decodificadas)?

Comment: No R tu não pode aplicar labels sem modificar os valores (de maneira similar ao que acontece no SPSS). Ao aplicar o factor, tua variável vai sempre ser transformada em um vetor de inteiros com uma 'máscara'. A única solução para isso, penso eu, é ter 2 data.frames diferentes: um com os valores iguais e outro com os valores codificados.

Comment: Acho que consegui o que eu estava querendo. Para criar as variáveis codificadas em novas colunas do data frame (e assim manter as colunas originais) eu alterei a última atribuição do `for` para `dados[,paste0(i,".new")] <- ...`. Ainda tenho que testar se isto impacta no loop já que a condição de parada é em função das colunas dos dados. Se der problema, talvez eu crie realmente um novo data frame só com as variáveis decodificadas.